# Перетаскивание одного div-a на другой мышью

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-tools

Как организовать возможность перетаскивания синего `box` на `block-2` при нажатой левой кнопке мыши?

Каркас страницы:

```css
.block-1
{
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
    float:left;
}

.block-2
{
    float:right;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background-color:red;
}

.box
{
    width:50px;
    height:50px;
    background-color:green; 
}
```

```html
<div class="block-1">
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
<div class="block-2"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно с помощью Jquery http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/#entry-examples

Можно так:

```js
function makeDroppable(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragBlock(e) {
  e.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", e.target.id);
}

function dropBlock(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  //При извлечении данных Вы должны использовать такой же тип как и при их сохранение
  var rdata = e.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");
  //Очистим содержимое перетаскиваемого элемента
  e.target.innerHTML = "";
  //Сделаем перетаскиваемый элемент элементом потомком принимающей области т.е. фактически мы 
  //переносим его в содержимое принимающего его элемента
  e.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(rdata))
}
```

```css
.block-1 {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
  float: left;
}
.block-2 {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
.box {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="block-1">
  <div class="box" draggable="true" ondragstart="dragBlock(event)" id="draggable-element"></div>
</div>
<div class="block-2" ondrop="dropBlock(event)" ondragover="makeDroppable(event)"></div>
```

*[ С помощью http://www.wisdomweb.ru/HTML5/draganddrop.php ]*